# What is the purpose of the "Grid" object type?

Tags: mesh, objects

From what I can tell the grid object type is just a subdivided plane. What is the difference between adding a plane and subdividing it, and adding a "grid"? If there is some **hidden** difference what is it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is any difference, other than it's slightly  faster to add a grid than to add a plane and subdivide.

From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Primitives#Grid):

> A standard grid is made out of n by m vertices. The resolution of the
>   x-axis and y-axis can be specified in the context panel in the Tool
>   Shelf which appears when the object is created; the higher the
>   resolution, the more vertices are created. Example objects that can be
>   created out of grids include landscapes (with the proportional editing
>   tool or Displace modifier) and other organic surfaces. **You can also
>   obtain a grid when you create a plane and then use a subdivide
>   modifier in Edit mode.**

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>